# Import custom plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I created my plugin using plug-in development of eclipse, and now I want to import my plugin to eclipse, I searched everywhere, they say that I should go Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive but when I add jar file of my plugin eclipse says 'No software site found at ..', I have no site, how can I add my plugin?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: A plugin without a feature and update site cannot be installed via _Help > Install New Software_. Just put it into the `dropins` folder of your Eclipse installation directory.

Comment: @howlger - thanks, I added the jar file to dropins folder, should I do something after that? I added then I closed and opened eclipse again but my plugin wasn't added to eclipse

Comment: It is not shown in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Plug-ins_? Then maybe a requirement is missing.

Comment: @howlger - the file I put in dropins is jar, is it ok? if yes what requirements does a plugin need to run?

Comment: Yes, assuming the JAR is an Eclipse plugin JAR. Please show  `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file that contained is in the JAR.

Comment: @howlger - `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ImportJPOs
Bundle-SymbolicName: ImportJPOs;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.26.100",
 org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.202.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.18.200",
 org.eclipse.jdt.core;bundle-version="3.33.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.20.100"
Automatic-Module-Name: ImportJPOs
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
`

Comment: Yes, that seems to be an Eclipse plugin/bundle. It requires running Eclipse with Java 17 or higher and five plugins/bundles from the Eclipse platform and JDT each of a given minimum version.

Comment: @howlger - I have searched again and then I found this [link](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html) but when I want to add the plugin eclipse says that "... requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.ui 3.202.0' but it could not be found" I've tried to import osgi.bundle to my plugin but eclipse won't find it when I enter the name of dependency

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui 3.202.0` means plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.ui` of version 3.202.0 or higher. Either your plugin requires a too high version of  `org.eclipse.ui` or the Eclipse into you want to install your plugin is too old. Putting a higher version of `org.eclipse.ui` into the `dropins` wouldn't work either, since that will break other requirements.

Comment: @howlger - The eclipse version I want to install this plugin is 2022, is that version acceptable?

Comment: @howlger - Thank you so much for your help, I used previous version of plug-in development eclipse and my plugin imported to another eclipse without error, thanks for you time